# php form does not works

Tags: php, post

I write this code but it seems does not works absolutely :(

This is the result:

> Deprecated: Automatically populating $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is deprecated
>   and will be removed in a future version. To avoid this warning set
>   'always_populate_raw_post_data' to '-1' in php.ini and use the
>   php://input stream instead. in Unknown on line 0
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent in
>   Unknown on line 0
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: firstname in
>   C:\Users\Mizo\PhpstormProjects\untitled3\success.php on line 2
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: lastname in
>   C:\Users\Mizo\PhpstormProjects\untitled3\success.php on line 2
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: lastname in
>   C:\Users\Mizo\PhpstormProjects\untitled3\success.php on line 2
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: email in
>   C:\Users\Mizo\PhpstormProjects\untitled3\success.php on line 2

```
<?php
$firstname="";
$lastname="";
$email="";
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$_POST["firstname"]=$firstname;

$_POST["lastname"]=$lastname;

$_POST["email"]=$email;

?>

<form action="success.php" method="post">
<label for id="firstname">Firstname</label>
<input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname"  >
<br/>
<label for id="lastname">lastname</label>
<input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname"  >
<br/>
<label for  id="email">E-mail cím</label>
<input type="email" name="email" id="email" >
<br/>
<input type="submit">
</form>
success.php
<?php
echo"$firstname,$lastname,$email";
?>
```

Comment: Are you running your project on local environment?

Comment: easyphp... But I uploaded to webserver, and there is same problem.. Only I do not see the error messages, just the white death.

Answer (score 4):

I assumed what you meant to do was :

```
$firstname = $_POST["firstname"];

$lastname = $_POST["lastname"];

$email = $_POST["email"];
```

Also you didn't close the bracket of your if.

Answer (score 0):

However at the first glance you have semantic PHP errors (which @zoubida13 pointed out), I think you have earlier versions of PHP running as well.

Locate your `php.ini` file, then search for `always_populate_raw_post_data` directive and set its value to `-1`.

This warning appears regardless of whether your web app uses `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA`.